# Google Recaptcha v2 POST request getting blocked by Azure WAF, any solutions?

Tags: recaptcha

I am using Google Recaptcha v2 I'm not a Robot checkbox,

After submitting a form with the checkbox, a POST request with g-recaptcha-response in the body is sent to the application backend (for verification).

Everything is working as expected, but the problem arise when we are enabling Azure WAF in front of the application.
The POST request containing the g-recaptcha-response sometimes got blocked by following rules:

- 942430 Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection (args): # of special characters exceeded (12)
- 942440 SQL Comment Sequence Detected.

We can create exclusion rule to the violated rules for ARGS:g-recaptcha-response and recaptcha will work as expected, but if possible we prefer to not create the exclusion rule if possible.

My question: is there any workaround to avoid this Azure WAF Rule triggered? So that I don't have to create exclusion on the triggered Azure WAF Rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form using ajax and encode the response token in base64 before submission.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: link to from submission handler, 
  data: {
    'foo' : $("#foo").val(),
    'bar' : $("#bar").val(),
    'g-recaptcha-response' : btoa(grecaptcha.getResponse())
  },            
  success: function (response) {
    handle returned response
  }
});
```

Then on the submission handler page, unencode the response before sending the verification check to Google.